# Java temperature convertor error

Tags: java, calculator

I have made this program but can't figure out what is wrong, basically it is a converter of C->F, F->C, C->K, K->C, F->K, K->F. BTW this is my first question on this site and i use Bluej. When i try converting it i get a false answer but my formula's are all correct (checked on google)...

```js
/**
 * Program to 
 * 
 * Anirudh Gupta
 * th August 2014
 */
import java.io.*;
public class Temperature
{
   public static void main () throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
       System.out.println("Enter choice of scale in which current temperature in:");
       System.out.println(" 1)Celsius");
       System.out.println(" 2)Fahrenheit");
       System.out.println(" 3)Kelvin");
       int no=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       double ans;
       switch(no)
       {
           case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature to convert(in °C)");
                double C=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter choice of scale to which current temperature should be converted");
                System.out.println("1)Fahrenheit");
                System.out.println("2)Kelvin");
                int no1=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                switch(no1)
                {
                    case 1:
                           ans=((9*C)/5)+32;
                           System.out.println(ans+"°F");
                           break;
                    case 2:
                           ans=C+273;
                           System.out.println(ans+"K");
                           break;
                }
                break;
           case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature to convert(in °F)");
                double F=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter choice of scale to which current temperature should be converted");
                System.out.println("1)Celsius");
                System.out.println("2)Kelvin");
                int no2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                switch(no2)
                {
                    case 1:
                           ans=((5*(F-32))/9);
                           System.out.println(ans+"°C");
                           break;
                    case 2:
                           ans=((5/9)*(F-32))+273;
                           System.out.println(ans+"K");
                           break;
                }
                break;
           case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature to convert(in K)");
                double K=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter choice of scale to which current temperature should be converted");
                System.out.println("1)Celsius");
                System.out.println("2)Fahrenheit");
                int no3=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                switch(no3)
                {
                    case 1:
                           ans=K-273;
                           System.out.println(ans+"°C");
                           break;
                    case 2:
                           ans=((9/5)*(K-273))+32;
                           System.out.println(ans+"°F");
                           break;
                }
                break;
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please can you give examples of what conversions are incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(5/9)` will evaluate to zero as you're performing that calculation in *integer arithmetic*.

Similarly, `(9/5)` will evaluate to 1.

Rewrite as `5.0 / 9` etc. so the calculations take place in floating point.